# Getting error: "This webpage is not available" for my chrome app's options page

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

My CRX had the proper html page `options.html` in it, the manifest declares it properly (it shows up as a link on the chrome://extensions page) but when I click that link, Chrome gives the error:

> This webpage is not available
>
> The webpage at **chrome-extension://invalid/** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

It says "invalid" but the app runs perfectly well (all the content scripts run, the background created a database and saved to it). Why would it show as invalid? Why doesn't it have the extensions' id?

Here's the manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MyAPP",
    "description": "My App",
    "version": "0.0.0.32",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "27",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "icons": 
    {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "app": 
    {
        "background": 
        {
            "scripts": 
            [
                "scripts/background.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "permissions": 
    [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "fullscreen",
                {
            "fileSystem": 
            [
                "write"
            ]
        },
        "background",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Does it need to be declared in "web_accessible_resources"? Any idea what's wrong?

**Update**

Adding to "web_accessible_resources" does **not** fix the issue. I added everything on that page too.

**update 2**

It looks like it might be a Chrome bug for packaged apps. When I remove the `"app"` section in the manifest, it works! This is a bug since the Chrome app documentation states that apps can have options pages: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/options.html

Answer (score 1):

Options pages are only supported for extensions, you have indeed discovered a documentation bug (I've filed [issue 255079](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=255079)).

Comment: Why is that? That doesn't make sense. Apps should also have options pages. I'm building an app that runs in full page mode for a kiosk like experience and I cannot put any close buttons or admin navigation on there. Without an options page, I have to find weird work-arounds to allow them to get into settings. And options page would make this much easier.

Comment: Options pages open in Chrome tabs. Apps have no tabs, unless they implement something tab-like on their own. I could see the next question being "OK, so put the options page somewhere else. Why not do that?" But application frameworks typically don't provide high-level constructs such as options/settings/preferences pages, iOS being a notable exception. Typically they provide the primitives that you can use to build your own.

Comment: @sowbug But this is a problem on full-screen apps where you don't want to expose any settings/admin capabilities. Putting the options access into Chrome itself makes this much better.